# How to change Marker Icon using Google Api in Polymer-Project?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, polymer

help me please ,I generated multiple markers by using core-ajax, the default markers are shown well, but want to add the custom marker instead of the default red marker

```
<template repeat="{{x in views}}">
    <google-map-marker latitude="{{x.lat}}" longitude="{{x.long}}"
                       draggable="false">
            <img src="1.png" height="20px" width="20px">
    </google-map-marker>
</template>
```

as mentioned in the tutorial [this](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/#google-map-marker) but is not working

[image: the customized image position not set properly]

Comment: the tutorial says: marker with info window (children create the window content), the content of the <google-map-marker> will be the content of a panel shown after clicking on the marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this answer and dont know why people -ve the question about the google-map marker
**Solution**
we just add the specified icon using the icon attribute in the **google-map-marker**

```
<google-map-marker latitude="{{x.lat}}" 
        longitude="{{x.long}}"
        draggable="false"
        icon="components/elements/imagename.png"
        title="{{x.VDC}}-{{x.area}}">
</google-map-marker>
```

Comment: You can also find it in the google-map-marker [documentation](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/) (select google-map-marker from the dropdown menu). Says _icon - Image URL for the marker icon_.

Comment: When trying to use an animated .gif icon, it doesn't work